# how does this site do the hover effects?

Tags: css, hover

Please look at http://shaiya.aeriagames.com/ and tell me how they do their hover effects on the logo as it is not javascript and works in all browsers

Comment: i tried, but cant work it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *does* use Javascript. If you use Firebug and look at the image you can clearly see that another image is been overlaid above the original image with the CSS `opacity` property. Both images are attached as background images to two different elements. When you hover over the parent, the `li` with the id `gameLogo`, its child an anchor's opacity starts to increase from 0 to 1, thus causing the glow to 'appear', as both images are perfectly aligned.

You can see the overlaid image here: http://shaiya.aeriagames.com/themes/shaiya/images/site/page-header-light-hovers.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It's javascript - using the mootools library.
View the source of the page, and you will see near the bottom, theres this bit of code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s.aeriagames.com/modules/js/mootools-1.2.4-core.js"></script>...<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s.aeriagames.com/themes/shaiya/js/page.js"></script>
```

http://s.aeriagames.com/themes/shaiya/js/page.js is the script that implements the functionality, where http://s.aeriagames.com/modules/js/mootools-1.2.4-core.js is the mootools lirary.